# Is Julia a suitable language to use for MCMC Bayesian inference?

Tags: julia

I have some code where I want use MCMC Bayesian inference.
How is the julia language and ecosystem for MCMC?
Do good packages exist?
Is it generally well suited to this kind of work?

Comment: Turing.jl is the one I would recommend.

Comment: Please do not down/close vote without commenting in a way that helps. This is not how we treat new users to the Julia community. Given that many of these close votes are not from people in the Julia community and how these other individuals are deleting the answers, I have to apologize @maurouane1994 for the inability to respond. You may be able to get a better response [on the Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/) where the mods and community standards prevent such issues, for example [this link](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/mcmc-landscape/25654) is a good answer.